# Access localStorage array by index

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access localStorage value by a specific name and fullfill the condition. For an instance, my localStorage has been saved like this in chrome which is fine.

```
[{"id":"checkboxForTheme","value":true},{"id":"checkboxForLinks","value":true}];
```

Key name is settings for above localStorage.

Now,  my JS looks something like this:

```
    var settings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settings'));
```

So far, it is all good. The only problem i'm facing right now is I'm unable to check the condition. For example, I want to check if checkboxForTheme is true or false and based on that I set Attribute data-theme= dark to body.

Here's my code that is not working:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("settings") !== null) {


    if (settings[0].value == "true") {
               document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        }    else if (settings[0].value == "false") {
               document.documentElement.removeAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        }

}
```

Basically I'd prefer to check setting['checkboxForTheme'].value if possible. That way, even if I change the position of localStorage indexes, it should still work.

Any idea how I can make this work? 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide your localstorage data .

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama
[{"id":"checkboxForTheme","value":true},{"id":"checkboxForLinks","value":true}];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already did `JSON.parse` from getItem, you use it like this (treat like regular boolean value)

```
if (settings.find(x => x.id === "checkboxForTheme").value) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
} else {
  document.documentElement.removeAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing "true" to true as below example .

```
if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("settings"))) {
  if (settings[0].value == true) {
               document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        }    else if (settings[0].value == false) {
               document.documentElement.removeAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

While storing as an array is fine, I would suggest to store your values to localStorage as a JSON object rather than an array to make your code better and compact. This is a very common pattern in many projects.

like so:

```
{"checkboxForTheme":true,"checkboxForLinks":false}
```

You can use below code to set the localstorage key:

```
let jsonData = {checkboxForTheme:true,checkboxForLinks:false}
localStorage.setItem("settings", JSON.stringify(json))
```

You can use below code to get the localstorage key:

```
let a = localStorage.getItem("settings")
let o = JSON.parse(a)
```

Now, you can simply check the condition like this:

```
if(o.checkboxForTheme === true)
{
///code
}else{

//code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to change with your code:

- Single and double quotes do exactly the same thing, so you should stick to one type for consistency.
- You called `localStorage.getItem` twice when you could store its result in a variable.
- You parsed the result of `getItem("settings")` before checking if it was null, only to check if it is null later. You should reorganize your code so the `JSON.parse` code is only called after the check.
- `true` is a boolean value, `"true"` is a string. Unquote your bools everywhere and the comparison should work properly.

With that said, here's what it would look like if I wrote it:

```
let settingsString = localStorage.getItem("settings");
if (settingsString !== null) {
    let settings = JSON.parse(settingsString);
    let enableDarkTheme = settings[0].value;

    if (enableDarkTheme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    } else {
        document.documentElement.removeAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why you are storing the data in an array of objects with an id property however. A flat structure would be much easier to manipulate:

```
// json stored in localStorage
{
    enableDarkTheme: true,
    somethingAboutLinks: false
}

// code
let settings = JSON.parse(settingsString);
if (settings.enableDarkTheme) {
    ...
}
```

Note that I used `let` instead of `var` in my code. Unless you need to support old browsers, [I'd recommend using `let` variables all the time](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/274352/175520).

Answer (score 0):

This line `localStorage.getItem("settings")` checks if there exist a storage with this key. So once that is not null you need to parse it to array befor usinf the index

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("settings") !== null) {
  // convert string to array and then 
  const settings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("settings"))
  if (settings[0].value == "true") {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
  } else if (settings[0].value == "false") {
    document.documentElement.removeAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
  }

}
```